# CSS border duplicates in IE mobile view

Tags: css, internet-explorer, windows-phone, adaptive-design, lumia

thanks for taking the time to read this - really hoping someone can help me here.
I have an adaptive site (not responsive) and on this page:

http://www.findspace.co.uk/pages/3bed-student-accommodation-newcastle.html

I'm having an issue with a border-top style applied to the div 'containerDDbeds'. I'm using the border style to add a horizontal rule between each set of property information. The first three are done for illustration. It looks fine on the iPhone but on a Nokia Lumia 630 Windows phone in IE I get the rules duplicated (it may actually be the entire div that has the border on it) as shown in this Browserstack emulation. I only really need them above each property picture. I wonder if I need a hack for IE mobile views? The desktop version of the site is fine - it's just the mobile view. Any help or pointers would be greatfully received. Antony

Here's the link to the mobile css file [mobile css](http://www.findspace.co.uk/engine/css/mainm.css)

[image: Browser stack view for Nolia Lumia 630]

Comment: Check if your markup is valid with [validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

Comment: Thanks Vucko - it's bringing up various errors but none that seem to tie in with that particular border attribute? Unless I'm missing something? Antony

Comment: Well, first fix all your markup errors and then check if it's working.

Comment: Thanks Vucko - I'll try that.

Comment: Why not just use an actual horizontal rule and style it?

Comment: Thanks Gary - I considered that but wasn't sure how compliant that would be. I'm sure it would have worked just as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone that had a look at this for me.
I managed to fix it by placing a clearing div between each div 'containerDDbeds'.

Antony